# How to efficiently generate lower triangle indices of a symmetric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indices, triangular

I need to generate lower triangle matrix indices (row and columns pairs). The current implementation is inefficient (memory wise) specially when symmetric matrix gets big (more than 50K rows). Is there a better way?

```
rows <- 2e+01
id <- which(lower.tri(matrix(, rows, rows)) == TRUE, arr.ind=T)
head(id)

#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   3   1
# [3,]   4   1
# [4,]   5   1
# [5,]   6   1
# [6,]   7   1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
z <- sequence(rows)
cbind(
  row = unlist(lapply(2:rows, function(x) x:rows), use.names = FALSE),
  col = rep(z[-length(z)], times = rev(tail(z, -1))-1))
```

---

Benchmarks with larger data:

```
library(microbenchmark)

rows <- 1000
m <- matrix(, rows, rows)

## Your current approach
fun1 <- function() which(lower.tri(m) == TRUE, arr.ind=TRUE)

## An improvement of your current approach
fun2 <- function() which(lower.tri(m), arr.ind = TRUE)

## The approach shared in this answer
fun3 <- function() {
  z <- sequence(rows)
  cbind(
    row = unlist(lapply(2:rows, function(x) x:rows), use.names = FALSE),
    col = rep(z[-length(z)], times = rev(tail(z, -1))-1))
}

## Sven's answer
fun4 <- function() {
  row <- rev(abs(sequence(seq.int(rows - 1)) - rows) + 1)
  col <- rep.int(seq.int(rows - 1), rev(seq.int(rows - 1)))
  cbind(row, col)
}

microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), fun4())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq   median       uq       max neval
#  fun1() 77.813577 85.343356 90.60689 95.71648 130.40059   100
#  fun2() 73.812204 82.103600 85.87555 90.59235 138.66547   100
#  fun3()  9.016237  9.382506 10.63291 13.20085  55.42137   100
#  fun4() 20.591863 24.999702 28.82232 31.90663  65.05169   100
```

Comment: When I have `rows <- 1e+05` then `lapply` requires lots of memory to build the list, i.e. of order `O(n^2)`. Is there a way to rewrite `fun3()` so it can be called iteratively in a loop to return subsets of the index pairs, lets say 10K pairs a time?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is so slow because multiple matrices have to be created. You create the first matrix using `matrix`. The function `lower.tri` creates 3 matrices internally. The comparison of the result with `TRUE` creates a fifth matrix. By the way: The comparison with `TRUE` is unnecessary.

The following approach does not create any matrix, but calculates the indices:

```
rows <- 2e+01 # number of rows and columns (20)

x <- rev(abs(sequence(seq.int(rows - 1)) - rows) + 1)
y <- rep.int(seq.int(rows - 1), rev(seq.int(rows - 1)))

idx <- cbind(x, y)
```

(If you want a slightly faster approach, you can assign the result of `seq.int(rows - 1)` to a variable instead of using this command three times.)

Compare with original solution:

```
id <- which(lower.tri(matrix(, rows, rows)) == TRUE, arr.ind=T)

all(id == idx)
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified and faster version of the `fun3` method from the accepted answer (`rep.int` is faster than `rep`, `1:rows` is faster than `sequence(rows)`, `(rows-1):1` was slightly faster than `rev(z[-rows])`, and `use.names=F` is not needed):

```
rows=5
z=1:rows
cbind(unlist(lapply(z[-1],function(x)x:rows)),rep(z[-rows],(rows-1):1))
```

Or if you don't save the sequence in a variable, then the code becomes a bit slower but easier to understand:

```
cbind(unlist(lapply(2:rows,function(x)x:rows)),rep(1:(rows-1),(rows-1):1))
```

`1:n` is faster than `sequence(n)` and `seq.int(n)`:

```
> n=1e6;microbenchmark(sequence(n),1:n,seq(n),seq.int(n))
Unit: nanoseconds
          expr    min        lq       mean    median        uq     max neval
   sequence(n) 420147 1397684.5 1295462.89 1428241.5 1466248.0 2016984   100
           1:n    129     160.0     561.22     242.5     617.0    4028   100
        seq(n)   3596    4045.5    7538.04    5081.5   11194.5   23921   100
    seq.int(n)    235     289.5    1001.95     502.5    1737.0    5265   100
```

`rep.int` is faster than `rep`:

```
> z1=1:100;z2=100:1;microbenchmark(times=1000,rep.int(z1,z2),rep(z1,z2))
Unit: microseconds
            expr    min     lq     mean median      uq    max neval
 rep.int(z1, z2) 28.058 28.351 28.76671 28.490 28.9725 69.061  1000
     rep(z1, z2) 29.553 29.849 30.29978 29.963 30.4945 85.321  1000
```

This is an easy but slow way to generate the indexes of the lower triangle:

```
combn(rows,2)
```

This procedural method is also slow:

```
o=matrix(,(rows^2-rows)/2,2)
n=1;for(i in 1:(rows-1))for(j in(i+1):rows){o[n,]=c(j,i);n=n+1}
o
```

But the Rcpp version of the procedural method is much faster:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix pairij_cpp(int n){
  NumericMatrix out(n*(n-1)/2,2);
  int row=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++)for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){out(row,0)=j;out(row++,1)=i;}
  return out;
}')
```

This shows the median time in ms for each number of rows:

```
     10    100   1000
0.01682 0.2700  24.32 fun1
0.01623 0.2380  20.01 fun2
0.02830 0.1717   5.69 fun3
0.01456 0.1440   9.75 fun4
0.01506 0.1440   5.31 fun3_simplified
0.01436 0.1622   7.35 fun3_simplified_no_variable
0.05219 2.9143 296.11 comb
0.05249 4.9847 520.86 procedural_matrix
0.06642 6.5620 682.25 procedural_vector
0.00360 0.0461   2.80 pairij_cpp(rows)
```

Benchmark code:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericMatrix pairij_cpp(int n){
  NumericMatrix out(n*(n-1)/2,2);
  int row=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++)for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){out(row,0)=j;out(row++,1)=i;}
  return out;
}')

size=c(10,100,1000)
r=sapply(size,function(rows){
  m=matrix(,rows,rows)
  b=microbenchmark(times=100,
    fun1={which(lower.tri(m)==T,arr.ind=T)},
    fun2={which(lower.tri(m),arr.ind=T)},
    fun3={z=sequence(rows);cbind(row=unlist(lapply(2:rows,function(x)x:rows),use.names=F),col=rep(z[-length(z)],times=rev(tail(z,-1))-1))},
    fun4={row=rev(abs(sequence(seq.int(rows-1))-rows)+1);col=rep.int(seq.int(rows-1),rev(seq.int(rows-1)));cbind(row,col)},
    fun3_simplified={z=1:rows;cbind(unlist(lapply(z[-1],function(x)x:rows)),rep.int(z[-rows],(rows-1):1))},
    fun3_simplified_no_variable={cbind(unlist(lapply(2:rows,function(x)x:rows)),rep.int(1:(rows-1),(rows-1):1))},
    comb={c=t(combn(rows,2));c[,2:1]},
    procedural_matrix={o=matrix(,(rows^2-rows)/2,2);n=1;for(i in 1:(rows-1))for(j in(i+1):rows){o[n,]=c(j,i);n=n+1};o},
    procedural_vector={o=integer(rows^2-rows);n=1;for(i in 1:(rows-1))for(j in(i+1):rows){o[n]=j;o[n+1]=i;n=n+2};matrix(o,,2,T)},
    pairij_cpp(rows)
  )
  a=aggregate(b$time,list(b$expr),median)
  setNames(a[,2]/1e6,a[,1])
})

r2=apply(r,2,function(x)formatC(x,max(0,3-ceiling(log10(min(x,na.rm=T)))),format="f"))
r3=apply(rbind(size,r2),2,function(x)formatC(x,max(nchar(x)),format="s"))
writeLines(apply(cbind(r3,c("",rownames(r))),1,paste,collapse=" "))
```