# Handling large matrix with limited memory in R: how to get lower triangle?

Tags: r, large-data

I have a large matrix `bd` (25k by 25k) with numeric value, a sample of content which is here

```
> bd[1:5, 1:5]
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.8121698 0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000
[2,] 2.0770875 2.0159531 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.3688963 1.6658982 2.299720 0.000000 0.0000000
[4,] 1.5845495 0.4880238 1.538353 1.536267 0.0000000
[5,] 1.1428052 0.7087784 1.656545 1.077034 0.4592339
```

The variable size is 4.7GB so I want to reduce this into a vector of just the lower triangle values to save space.

However when I do `smallbd <- bd[lower.tri(bd, T)]` I get `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.3 Gb`

Any suggestions how else I can take the lower triangle within the memory constraint?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898684/how-to-efficiently-generate-lower-triangle-indices-of-a-symmetric-matrix

Comment: How do you create this matrix? What do you intend to do with it? Possibly a sparse matrix (from package Matrix) could be an option?

Comment: Thanks Pascal will try that.

@Roland it's a distance table between 25k points, adapted from answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958646/calculate-euclidean-distance-matrix-using-a-big-matrix-object/31615523#31615523 .

Comment: @Ricky If you use a self-written function why do you store those zeros? You should take a lesson from the `dist` function.

Comment: I used `dist`, it worked for smaller matrices but failed due to memory limitation when I reached about 25k by 25k. I'm experimenting with the approach from the other answer using `bigmemory`.

But we are detracting from the topic of my question actually. I'm interested to know how to get the triangle for big matrix like this regardless of the source; it could have been read from a huge csv.

Comment: `lower.tri` actually creates another 25k x 25k matrix. And the assignment creates at least one temporary matrix before the assignment is complete. If you want to save space, then look at the functions in the Matrix package. I'm quite sure it has a triangular type.

Comment: See: Packed Triangular Dense Matrices - "dtpMatrix" in pkg:Matrix

Comment: I did not say you should use `dist`. Your function should return the same kind of object as `dist` (with the same structure and class).

Comment: Thanks @42 for the suggestion. I was able to create a lower triangle , let's say `ntp`, of class `ntpMatrix`, but it cannot be used as a subset. I.e. `smallbd <- bd[ntp]` resulted in `Error in bd[ntp] : invalid subscript type 'S4'` . Does it mean this won't work, or did I do something wrongly?